# Changing the diagonal elements of BlockMatrix

Tags: apache-spark, matrix, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib, diagonal

I have a block matrix of size 4*4

```
Blockmatrix = 
    0.0  2.0  1.0  2.0
    2.0  0.0  2.0  4.0
    1.0  2.0  0.0  3.0
    2.0  4.0  3.0  0.0
```

While typing the type of this matrix,

It is showing

```
<class 'pyspark.mllib.linalg.distributed.BlockMatrix'>
```

I want to change only the diagonal element to **1.0**.

When I tried this piece of code,

```
diagonal_matrix = DenseMatrix(dataframe_item.numRows,dataframe_item.numCols,dataframe_item.toLocalMatrix().rowIter().zipWithIndex().flatMap(lambda x:(x[1].toArray(x[2]),x[1].toArray())).toArray())
```

It is throwing the following error,

```
AttributeError: 'DenseMatrix' object has no attribute 'rowIter'
```

Can anyone help to solve this error?
Or is there any better way to change diagonal values of BlockMatrix in Pyspark?

Comment: `DenseMatrix` is not a distributed matrix. You want a `numpy array` or a collected matrix as  a result?

Comment: I dont want a numpy array. I want it back as a BlockMatrix in pyspark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```py
from pyspark.mllib.linalg.distributed import *

rdd = sc.parallelize([
    (0, 0.0 , 2.0 , 1.0,  2.0),
    (1, 2.0 , 0.0 , 2.0 , 4.0),
    (2, 1.0 , 2.0 , 0.0 , 3.0),
    (3, 2.0 , 4.0  ,3.0  ,0.0)
    ])

Blockmatrix = IndexedRowMatrix(rdd.map(lambda x: IndexedRow(x[0],x[1:]))).toBlockMatrix()
```

This gives us the `Blockmatrix`.

Now, to replace diagonal elements with `1.0`, we use indices of rows. Hence, we convert the `BlockMatrix` to `IndexedRowMatrix` and then to `rdd`. Hence we have indices and rows.

We then change all diagonal elements to `1.0` using indices and then convert it back to `IndexedRowMatrix` and then to `BlockMatrix`.

```py
Blockmatrix_new = IndexedRowMatrix(Blockmatrix.toIndexedRowMatrix().rows\
                 .map(lambda x: IndexedRow(x.index, [1.0 if i == x.index else v for i,v in enumerate(x.vector)])))\
                 .toBlockMatrix()
```

`Blockmatrix_new` is the desired matrix. To view the contents, we convert it to local matrix. But remember that this will result in the matrix being collected.

```py
print Blockmatrix_new.toLocalMatrix()

DenseMatrix([[1., 2., 1., 2.],
             [2., 1., 2., 4.],
             [1., 2., 1., 3.],
             [2., 4., 3., 1.]])
```